# Which Lucene Analyzer should be used Korean language analysis?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I'm researching the best Lucene analyzer for processing Korean text.

Amazon CloudSearch has support for Korean but I suspect they are just using the CJK Analyzer.

The only ElasticSearch [plugin](https://github.com/jaeyoi/elasticsearch-analysis-korean) for Korean I've found has not been updated in years. The plugin appears to be built using a [Lucene Korean Analyzer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4956) where development has stalled for over a year.

How are you processing Korean text with Lucene, Solr or ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [cjk analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#cjk-analyzer):

```
"field": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "cjk"
}
```